# JavaFX - move projectiles

Tags: java, javafx, game-physics

First of all, this is my very first post here. Hello everyone!

I am a beginner in Java/JavaFX. Currently I wrote some simple "game" to learn some basic stuff in game development, doing that just for fun right now.
So far I get a player which moves to the left/right (movement is unrestricted, but never mind that now) and fires projectiles. I got this done, code below:

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Tester extends Application {

    private int dx, x = 150, y = 470, projectileSpeed = 10;
    private int counter = 0, spawnTime = 180, enemySpeed = 4;
    private boolean goLeft, goRight, isShooting;

    public final static int APP_WIDTH = 300;
    public final static int APP_HEIGHT = 500;

    private AnchorPane root;
    private Scene scene;

    private Rectangle projectile;
    private Circle player = new Circle(x, y, 10, Color.RED);
    private Rectangle enemy;
    private ArrayList<Rectangle> projectiles = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<Rectangle> enemies = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        root = new AnchorPane();
        scene = new Scene(root, APP_WIDTH, APP_HEIGHT, Color.GHOSTWHITE);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

        root.getChildren().addAll(player);

        loop();
    }

    private void controls() {

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            KeyCode key = event.getCode();

            switch (key) {
                case LEFT:
                    goLeft = true;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    goRight = true;
                    break;
                case SPACE:
                    projectiles.add(projectile = new Rectangle(3, 3, Color.BLUE));
                    projectile.relocate(x + player.getRadius(), y);
                    root.getChildren().add(projectile);
                    break;
            }

        });
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            KeyCode key = event.getCode();

            switch (key) {
                case LEFT:
                    goLeft = false;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    goRight = false;
                    break;
                case SPACE:
                    isShooting = false;
                    break;
            }

        });

    }

    private void shoot() {
        for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); ++i) {
            if (projectiles.get(i).getLayoutY() > (root.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - projectile.getHeight())) {
                projectiles.get(i).relocate(projectiles.get(i).getLayoutX(), (projectiles.get(i).getLayoutY() - projectileSpeed));
            } else {
                projectiles.remove(i);
                root.getChildren().remove(i);
            }
        }

    }

    private void spawnEnemy() {

        double spawnPosition = Math.random();

        int eWidth = 20;
        int eHeight = 40;
        double ex = (APP_WIDTH - eWidth) * spawnPosition;
        int ey = (int) (root.getBoundsInParent().getMinY());

        if (counter % spawnTime == 0) {
            enemies.add(enemy = new Rectangle(ex, ey, eWidth, eHeight));
            root.getChildren().add(enemy);
        }
    }

    public void moveEnemy() {
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); ++i) {
            if (enemies.get(i).getLayoutY() < (root.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY() + enemy.getHeight())) {
                enemies.get(i).relocate(enemies.get(i).getLayoutX(), (enemies.get(i).getLayoutY() + enemySpeed));
            } else {
                enemies.remove(i);
                
            }
        }
    }

    private void loop() {

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                controls();
                if (goLeft) {
                    dx = -5;
                }
                if (goRight) {
                    dx = 5;
                }
                if (!goLeft && !goRight) {
                    dx = 0;
                }
                player.relocate(x += dx, y);
                shoot();

                counter++;
                spawnEnemy();
                moveEnemy();
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Now the weird part.
If I comment the moveEnemy() method out, everything seems OK - the "enemies" (black rectangles) appear in random places along the x axis on the top of the root.

I thought I'll move enemies by means of the same method which I used to move projectiles. However, if I actually use this, my enemies keep appearing at the left top corner and dissappear almost instantly.
Why is that?

Many thanks!

Edit: maybe I wasn't clear. I don't expect a ready-made solution, but an explanation.

Comment: just curious: why do you register a new onKeyXX handler in each loop?

Comment: your move seems to be incorrect: don't you want to move it in x-direction? also the remove in the else block will cause trouble: you do it while looping thus decreasing the size of the enemies list ..

Comment: @kleopatra, you're right, putting thoes handlers in the loop was idiotic, didn't even notice it, thanks! Also deleted remove methods from else statements.
As far as the movement direction is concerned, the "enemies" shall move downwards (y+), towards the "player".

Comment: Ok, I got the code working!
One more thing: as @kleopatra pointed out, the remove() method in the else statements will cause problems. 
So now the question is: how to properly dispose of the projectiles and enemies which go outside the root pane?

Comment: use an Iterator (and its remove) or loop from the end ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it sorted out, thanks kleopatra for help! Probably there is still a room for improvement, but nonetheless its some progress:

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Tester extends Application {

    private int dx, x = 150, y = 470, projectileSpeed = 10;
    private int counter = 0, spawnTime = 180, enemySpeed = 4;
    private boolean goLeft, goRight, isShooting;

    public final static int APP_WIDTH = 300;
    public final static int APP_HEIGHT = 500;

    private AnchorPane root;
    private Scene scene;

    private Rectangle projectile;
    private Circle player = new Circle(x, y, 10, Color.RED);
    private Rectangle enemy;

    private ArrayList<Rectangle> projectiles = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<Rectangle> enemies = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        root = new AnchorPane();
        scene = new Scene(root, APP_WIDTH, APP_HEIGHT, Color.GHOSTWHITE);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

        root.getChildren().addAll(player);

        controls();
        loop();
    }

    private void controls() {

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            KeyCode key = event.getCode();

            switch (key) {
                case LEFT:
                    goLeft = true;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    goRight = true;
                    break;
                case SPACE:
                    if (!isShooting) {
                        projectiles.add(projectile = new Rectangle(2, 10, Color.ORANGERED));
                        projectile.relocate(x + player.getRadius(), y);
                        root.getChildren().add(projectile);
                        isShooting = true;
                        break;
                    }
            }

        });
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            KeyCode key = event.getCode();

            switch (key) {
                case LEFT:
                    goLeft = false;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    goRight = false;
                    break;
                case SPACE:
                    isShooting = false;
                    break;
            }

        });

    }

    private void shoot() {
        for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); ++i) {
            projectiles.get(i).relocate(projectiles.get(i).getLayoutX(), (projectiles.get(i).getLayoutY() - projectileSpeed));
        }

        Iterator<Rectangle> iterator = projectiles.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            projectile = iterator.next();
            if (projectile.getLayoutY() < root.getLayoutY()) {

                iterator.remove();
                root.getChildren().remove(projectile);

            }
        }

    }

    private void spawnEnemy() {

        double spawnPosition = Math.random();

        int eWidth = 20;
        int eHeight = 40;
        double ex = (int) ((APP_WIDTH - eWidth) * spawnPosition);
        int ey = (int) (root.getLayoutY());

        if (counter % spawnTime == 0) {

            enemy = new Rectangle(eWidth, eHeight);
            enemy.relocate(ex, ey);
            enemies.add(enemy);
            root.getChildren().add(enemy);
        }

    }

    public void moveEnemy(int delta) {

        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); ++i) {
            enemies.get(i).setY(enemies.get(i).getY() + delta);
        }

        Iterator<Rectangle> iterator = enemies.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            enemy = iterator.next();
            if (enemy.getLayoutY() < root.getLayoutY()) {

                iterator.remove();
                root.getChildren().remove(enemy);

            }
        }
    }

    private void loop() {

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                if (goLeft) {
                    dx = -5;
                }
                if (goRight) {
                    dx = 5;
                }
                if (!goLeft && !goRight) {
                    dx = 0;
                }
                player.relocate(x += dx, y);
                shoot();

                counter++;

                spawnEnemy();
                moveEnemy(4);

            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Now I'll play with the code a bit, try detecting collisions, restricting movement, adding some more stuff etc.